# Clustered Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

We have created a little spring boot application with Camel embedded.  It simply polls an Office365 mailbox via imap for unread emails.

We have some verbose logging and we have seen Box one consumes the message and then processes it (sends some REST requests) and finishes.  2s later after box 1 has finished box 2 picks the same message up and processes it.

We implemented an Idempotent consumer:

```
from(casesMailBox.getUri()).idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.headers.Message-ID}"), repo).routeId("messaging").process(emailToCaseProcessor);
```

We can see duplicate entries in the underlying Oracle tables.

The documents are not clear but I assume the idempotentConsumer would commit as soon as possible to the DB.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Idempotent consumer will not work in clustered environment as idempotent repository is a in-memory one.

You have to use central database or Hazelcast data grid based implementation.

For more info refer: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

**Zookeeper,**

If you want to use polling consumer; scheduler in a clustered environment and want to avoid duplicate route triggering, you can use zookeeper with route policy.

Ref:http://camel.apache.org/zookeeper.html

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hello it is using a JDBCMessagIdRepository. So I am not using the in memory one.